# <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h> file not found in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, google-maps, cocoapods

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding Google Maps.  I am using Pod.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target 'EmployeeConnectOCS' do
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
end
```

It is also install successfully. My project was working fine but now it is showing:

```
<GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h> file not found
```

I have tried things on the Internet but nothing helps me. Google framework file already exist in the project but it is showing error, and I am not understanding the issue.

It exist in project as in the image:

[image]

And my other linking flag file is

[image]

[image]

Showing like this

```
[!] The `EmployeeConnectOCS [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-EmployeeConnectOCS/Pods-EmployeeConnectOCS.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `EmployeeConnectOCS [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-EmployeeConnectOCS/Pods-EmployeeConnectOCS.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136689/discussion-on-question-by-muju-googlemaps-googlemaps-h-file-not-found-in-objec).